# Почему стираются старые объекты из ListView?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```cs
public ObservableCollection < MyListModel > DialogsListMessages {
  get;
  set;
}
public ObservableCollection < MyListModel > MessagesList {
  get;
  set;
}

public MyListPageViewModel(string type, string message) {
  MessagesList = new ObservableCollection < MyListModel > ();

  if (type == "MyMessage") {
    SendMessage(message);
    return;
  }

  MessagesList.Add(new MyListModel {
    ColumnUser = "1", Name = "Мурат Корнеев", Image = "https://millionstatusov.ru/pic/statpic/all8/5e04c21a52a39.jpg", Detail = "Чекни мое сообщение!"
  });
  MessagesList.Add(new MyListModel {
    ColumnUser = "0", Name = "Алехей Махабаев", Image = "https://sun9-4.userapi.com/impf/c831209/v831209343/17ee0f/KgFU0iacCMM.jpg?size=200x267&quality=96&sign=e927921a750a8c0e44aa701e4312db8e&c_uniq_tag=slZ7WRlji5tOmD0GheLv_OfshwBa8Cipms3Qr2siL4Q&type=album", Detail = "Когда деньги?"
  });
  MessagesList.Add(new MyListModel {
    ColumnUser = "1", Name = "Мурат Корнеев", Image = "https://millionstatusov.ru/pic/statpic/all8/5e04c21a52a39.jpg", Detail = "Я не дам твои деньги"
  });
  MessagesList.Add(new MyListModel {
    ColumnUser = "0", Name = "Алехей Махабаев", Image = "https://sun9-4.userapi.com/impf/c831209/v831209343/17ee0f/KgFU0iacCMM.jpg?size=200x267&quality=96&sign=e927921a750a8c0e44aa701e4312db8e&c_uniq_tag=slZ7WRlji5tOmD0GheLv_OfshwBa8Cipms3Qr2siL4Q&type=album", Detail = "Почему"
  });
  MessagesList.Add(new MyListModel {
    ColumnUser = "1", Name = "Мурат Корнеев", Image = "https://millionstatusov.ru/pic/statpic/all8/5e04c21a52a39.jpg", Detail = "Потому что я бомж"
  });
  MessagesList.Add(new MyListModel {
    ColumnUser = "0", Name = "Алехей Махабаев", Image = "https://sun9-4.userapi.com/impf/c831209/v831209343/17ee0f/KgFU0iacCMM.jpg?size=200x267&quality=96&sign=e927921a750a8c0e44aa701e4312db8e&c_uniq_tag=slZ7WRlji5tOmD0GheLv_OfshwBa8Cipms3Qr2siL4Q&type=album", Detail = "Пошел!"
  });

}

public void SendMessage(string message) {

  MessagesList = new ObservableCollection < MyListModel > ();
  MessagesList.Add(new MyListModel {
    ColumnUser = "1", Name = "Rer", Image = "https://millionstatusov.ru/pic/statpic/all8/5e04c21a52a39.jpg", Detail = "REr"
  });

}
```

Когда я нажимаю кнопку, то действует функция `SendMessage`, после функции стираются все объекты и создается новый. Что не так?

Если убрать `new`, то будет ошибка:Невызываемый `ObservableCollection<T>` не может использоваться как метод

```cs
MessagesList = ObservableCollection < MyListModel > ();

MessagesList.Add(MyListModel {
  ColumnUser = "1", Name = "Rer", Image = "https://millionstatusov.ru/pic/statpic/all8/5e04c21a52a39.jpg", Detail = "REr"
});
```

Где убрана инцилизация

```cs
        public void SendMessage(string message)
        { 

            MessagesList.Add(new MyListModel { ColumnUser = "1", Name = "Rer", Image = "https://millionstatusov.ru/pic/statpic/all8/5e04c21a52a39.jpg", Detail = "REr" });

        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы как думаете, "почему"? Наверно потому, что вы постоянно пересоздаете коллекцию, не?

Comment: Я новичок в этом плане. Читал, что ObservableCollection как раз собирает все объекты и можно в него добавить свой объект

Comment: Новичок в каком плане? Вы не знаете, что если сделать `var ... = new SomeClass();`, то это будет создание __нового объекта__ или что? Вот представьте, что у вас есть корзинка, в нее вы собираете фрукты, вот в вашем коде, вы выкидываете эту корзинку с уже собранными фруктами и берете новую (`new ObservableCollection`). Тут не надо быть гением по Xamarin или коллекциям, это базовые понятия объектов в C#.

Comment: Новичок в Си шарпе. Я знаю, что такое new ( До этого Жс изучал ) , но дело в том, что если убрать, то будет ошибка якобы "является тип который недопустим в данном контексте переменная"

Comment: Не может такого быть. Показывайте значит код, который эту ошибку дает.

Comment: ``   
 public class MyListModel
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Detail { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Ingredients { get; set; }
        public string HorizontalOptions { get; set; }
        public string VerticalOptions { get; set; }
        public string ColumnUser { get; set; }

    }
``
На этот класс ругается, если убрать new. Чувствую себя тупым :)

Comment: Вам удобно читать код выше? Мне нет. Все нужно добавляйте в вопрос (кнопка править по ним). И да, я вас не класс просил дать, а код, где вы убрали `new`, после которого выдает ошибки.

Comment: Обновил и добавил код

Comment: `MessagesList = ObservableCollection<MyListModel>();` - вы серьезно? Я вам сказал `new` убрать, это не просто `new` убрать, а убрать полностью строку, где вы инициализируете коллекцию повторно (берете новую корзинку), а вы бездумно взяли и убрали лишь слово `new`...

Comment: Но если убрать эту полностью строку, то будет ругаться якобы объект не инцилизирован

Comment: Вы его уже инициализировали ранее, в конструкторе... А потом инициализируете повторно, при каждой "отправке сообщения". Ну подумайте вы уже логически.

Comment: Да я это знаю, что у меня заранее уже инцилизирован, но все равно вызывает ошибку при добавление нового сообщения "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Comment: Выдает ошибку - показывайте код.

Comment: `MessagesList.Add(new MyListModel { ColumnUser = "1", Name = "Rer", Image = "https://millionstatusov.ru/pic/statpic/all8/5e04c21a52a39.jpg", Detail = "REr" });`

Comment: 1. В вопрос. 2. КОД, где вы убрали инициализацию, после которой у вас ошибка, а не непонятный обрывок...

Comment: Все, обновил вопрос

Comment: Почему у вас на скрине вдруг начал отличаться код от того, что в вопросе? [Что это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVcuQ.png)? Что за `DialogsListMessages`, куда пропала инициализация `MessagesList = new ObservableCollection < MyListModel > ();`?

Comment: **DialogsListMessages** не обращать внимание, это уже в другом месте вообще находиться, убрал потому что этот кусок кода вообще никак не имеет значение к нашем вопросе. А инцилизацию убрал в функции

Comment: Я вам пишу: `Вы его уже инициализировали ранее, в конструкторе...`, а вы мне пишете: `А инцилизацию убрал в функции`. Где первая инициализация? Которая была в конструкторе тогда?

Comment: Сейчас только что дошло, что эта инцилизация не находится в конструктере, а в публике